# Class PHPUnitLogger cannot extend from interface PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit

I was installing Eclipse and PHPUnit on Windows and tried to run a test provided with PHPUnit but i got this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class PHPUnitLogger cannot extend from interface PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter in C:\Users\lmarques\AppData\Local\Temp\phpunit_printer\PHPUnitLogger.php(424) : eval()'d code on line 1`

In parallel, i need to force termination of execution and get this message at that moment:

`Cannot launch PHPUnit tests (port address 7478): Accept timed out`

I used composer to install PHPunit and also put configuration for phpunit.phar in Preferences/PHP/Tools/PHPUnit (https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/installation.html)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which phpunit version you use?

Comment: I use last released as of today: PHPUnit 9

Comment: PDT 7.1 correctly run PHPUnit 9 tests, but might have problem with warning/notices on PHPUnit 8.5 and above. This has been fixed in 7.2 dev snapshot

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit 9 has been released 7 Feb 2020 and is not supported by current stable Eclipse PHP Development Tools.

Support for this version will be part of upcoming PDT 7.1.

Bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=559932